# Declaring a variable and inserting into temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, temp-tables

Why does the error show up?

```
declare @start_date date, @end_date date

set @start_date = '2018-06-01'
set @end_date = '2018-11-30' 
go

select * 
into mytable_TB 
from Other_Table 
where mis_date >= @start_date 
  and mis_date <= @end/_date
```

**Error:**

> Must declare the scalar variable @start_date

Anybody know the reason for this?

Comment: Remove `GO` from there

Comment: Variables have batch scope. Adding `GO` creates a new batch so the variable is not available there.

Answer (score 3):

Eliminate the Go in between variable declaration and select query, Hence GO is a batch separator to break the entire script up into batches

```
declare @start_date date, @end_date date

set @start_date = '2018-06-01'
set @end_date = '2018-11-30' 


select * into mytable_TB from Other_Table where mis_date >= @start_date 
and mis_date <= @end_date
```